# jQuery animate() to move div right, then left, on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to get a div to slide to the right and then back left on click. I currently have this code, but it slides right, then immediately slides back left without a second click. I also tried to implement toggle, but ended up breaking the script. I feel so close but can't seem to nail it.

```
$(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $("#click").animate({left:'+=100px'}, 'fast');
    });

    $("#click").click(function() {
        $("#click").animate({left:'0'}, 'fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/avuruz/5/edit)*

```
var c=0;
$("#click").click(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({left: ++c%2*100 }, 'fast');
});
```

**To explain the math behind this solution:**
after every click the `var c` gets pre-incremented so basically after 10 clicks `c` will be `== 10` and  using *modulus* `10%2 = 0`,
and if you continue to click the math is:
11%2 `=1` 
 12%2 `=0` 
 13%2 `=1` 
 14%2 `=0` ... and so on
if you multiply 1 by 100 = 100 (the 100px needed) and every even (0*100) will result in our 0px!

---

or like this:

```
var dir = 0;
$("#click").click(function(){
     dir = dir===0 ? 100 : 0;
     $(this).stop().animate({left: dir }, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: +1 nice custom toggle function, should do what the OP wanted!

Comment: Hey Roko, thought this would do the trick, but still seems to keep sliding right. http://jsfiddle.net/chris_s/jh3gh/

Comment: @chris_s You pasted some strange code in there. I reedited my answer with 2 examples. take a look - just paste the one you prefer into your fiddle or give a shot at my demo

Comment: @Roko, my bad. I was using the original code you put in. These work great and are exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @chris_s Sorry for loosing some minutes, the first code was my first attempt to remind me on the one I posted (demo provided) thx

Comment: @chris_s If you're not in common with the *modulus* operator I explained in details my first solution

Comment: @Roko I do understand the modulus, so I appreciate both solutions!

Answer (score 0):

That is because according to the first event the Div actually moves right by 100px.
 But you defined two click events right . So the event is called twice for each click.

So your div moves 100px accoding to the first function, then immediately the second function is fired and it moves back.

You can check this by placing an alert.. You can see two alerts even for a single click..

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine (either by the `left` offset value or by a variable) where the div is currently and according to that move it in the right direction (if it's left, move it right, and vice versa). So, basically an if-clause within a single click function handles this.

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to queue the two effects use .queue and .dequeue

You can see some examples and the spec here:
http://api.jquery.com/queue/